# How can I run a headless gvim to get syntax highlighted code converted to HTML?

Tags: linux, gvim

I want to generate HTML files in batch to show some gvim colorschemes in action. I took my current solution from the script at http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/, but this will open open a gvim window for each colorscheme I want to process.

So far, the only way I have found to avoid the annoying new windows that pop up every second is to start a VNCserver and set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to that of the VNCserver so that all gvim windows are sent to the display within the VNC session.

However, I would like to know if there is a way I can avoid the whole VNC setup and just run a headless gvim instance that does the conversion and exits, with no windows ever being actually displayed.

I'm using linux, BTW.

Answer (score 4):

```
vim -E -c "TOhtml" -c "w" -c "qa!" -- test.c >/dev/null
```

Use `vim`, it will load faster than `gvim`.
You can speed up the loading time a bit by using `-X`, or a No-X version of `vim`.

In order to silence it, use `>/dev/null`.
But that will make `vim` complain (`Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal`) and pause a bit, hence we use `-E`.

We could have tried `-E -s`, but I'm somehow unable to use `:TOhtml` properly, the result is uncolored, and is one a single line.

I pimp the command a little by using `-R -c "set noreadonly"` or better `-n` alone.
This prevents the usual warning message when opening a file that already has a swapfile.
There is nothing particular to prevent failures to open a non writable file (eg. owned by root).

See my [vimcat](https://github.com/ofavre/vimcat) repository at GitHub, for an example usage of vim syntax highlighting used in a terminal.

Comment: The colors aren't generated correctly unless it's done from gvim, unless you know a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell whether your problem is that Vim opens too many windows at once, or that it opens any windows at all...

The latter case I can't help you with, however, in any newer Vim, you can do something like this (very primitive, can probably be made a lot nicer):

```
# gvim -c TOhtml -c w -c q -c q test.c
```

which will create a test.c.xhtml based on the file test.c using the current color scheme.
Then, perhaps another -c to change the colors, stick it all in a shell script...

**EDIT:**

> with no windows ever being actually displayed.

Yeah, so, I'm a moron. Please disregard this post.